# Native Base Accordion, VirtualizedLists warning

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to work with `Accordion` in Native Base and it is returning an odd warning.

My code:

```
const dataMenus = [
  { title: "Credit Card", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Bank Account (for ACH payments)", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Recurring Payment", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
];
class MyAccount extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Container>
          <Content padder>
            <ScrollView>
              <Accordion dataArray={dataMenus} expanded={0}/>
            </ScrollView>
          </Content>
        </Container>
      );
    }
}
```

It is returning:
`VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.`

Thanks

Comment: you probably should embed `<ScrollView />` inside `<Accordion />` under `renderContent` props for this to work.

Comment: I don't have renderContent. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adding `renderContent` prop like this:

```
  renderSecondaryContent = ( item ) => {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          // height: 300
        }}
        horizontal={true}
      >
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Content
          // style={{ maxHeight: 200 }}
          padder
        >
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataMenus}
            expanded={0}
            renderContent={(dataMenus) => this.renderSecondaryContent(dataMenus.content)}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

i've also added a snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/nativebase-example-3) where you can experiment further. :)